# Add "s" to the end of each word in an array except for the 2nd element in the given array, only using one line of code

Tags: ruby, each, ternary-operator, collect

I have an array of single word strings, and I would like to add an 's' to the end of each single word strings except for the 2nd string(element) in the array. I can easily accomplish this using 9 lines of code, but would prefer to do it with 3 lines of code.

Here's my working code using 9 lines.

```
def add_s(array)
    array.each_with_index.collect do |element, index|
        if index == 1
            element
        else element[element.length] = "s"
            element
        end
    end
end
```

Here's my broken code while only trying to use 3 lines.

```
def add_s(array)
    array.each_with_index.map {|element, index| index == 1 ? element : element[element.length] = "s"}
end
```

Above will return...

```
array = ["hand", "feet", "knee", "table"]
add_s(array) => ["s", "feet", "s", "s"]
```

I'm trying to get...

```
array = ["hand", "feet", "knee", "table"]
add_s(array) => ["hands", "feet", "knees", "tables"]
```

Comment: Why do you want to add a `"s"` to these words? And why do you want to skip the second word on the list? This feels like a xy problem to me. Do you aim to pluralize the words? And did you realize the there is not "feets"? Please elaborate on this. Because the rule for pluralization are more complex, what if you had words like "octopus" or "person" in the list?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this in 1 line? By the way, this is absolutely trivial, since linebreaks are optional in Ruby. Just take your 9 lines of code and remove the linebreaks, then you have 1 line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should clearly distinguish methods *mutating* the receiver (the variable they are called on) vs *pure* methods having no side effects. Also, you should care about what the method returns if you are to use the result of the method.

Here the method for all indices (but `1`) returns `"s"` because it is what the block returns:

```
foo = "bar"
foo[foo.length] = "s"
#⇒ "s"
```

If you’ll check your *mutated* array afterward, you’ll see it was successfully modified to what you wanted.

```
input = %w[hand feet knee table]
def add_s(input)
  input.each_with_index.map do |element, index|
    index == 1 ? element : element[element.length] = "s"
  end
  input # ⇐ HERE :: return the mutated object
end
#⇒ ["hands", "feet", "knees", "tables"]
```

or even easier, do not *map*, just iterate and mutate:

```
input = %w[hand feet knee table]
def add_s(input)
  input.each_with_index do |element, index|
    element[element.length] = "s" unless index == 1
  end
end
```

---

Instead of mutating the array inplace, the preferred solution would be to return a modified version. For that you should *return* new values from a block:

```
def add_s(input)
  input.each_with_index.map do |element, index|
    index == 1 ? element : element + "s"
  end
end
#⇒ ["hands", "feet", "knees", "tables"]
```

---

If I were given such a task, I would maintain a list of elements to be skipped as well since sooner or later there will be more than one:

```
input = %w[hand feet knee scissors table]
to_skip = [1, 3]
def add_s(input)
  input.each_with_index.map do |element, index|
    next element if to_skip.include?(index)
    element + "s"
  end
end
#⇒ ["hands", "feet", "knees", "scissors", "tables"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
["hand", "feet", "knee", "table"].map.with_index{|v,i| i==1 ? v : v + 's'}
#=> ["hands", "feet", "knees", "tables"]
```

`map.with_index` helps.
Basically `map.with_index` equals to `each_with_index.collect`.
`each` with `collect`(same as `map`) is superfluous.

If you want to mutate original array, you can change `+` to `<<`, but not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following to achieve as per provided words,

```
arr = ['apple', 'knee', 'crab', 'jails']
arr.each_with_index.map { |x,i| i == 1  ? x : x + 's' }
=> ["apples", "knee", "crabs", "jailss"]
```

but to avoid unwanted extra 's' at the end of the strings,

```
arr = ['apple', 'knee', 'crab', 'jails']
arr.each_with_index.map { |x,i| i == 1 || x[-1] == 's' ? x : x + 's' }
=> ["apples", "knee", "crabs", "jails"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Linebreaks in Ruby are completely optional, they can always be replaced by a keyword, a semicolon, or sometimes removed altogether. Therefore, it is always trivially possible to write any Ruby program, no matter how complex, in one line.

Here's your code in one line:

```
def add_s(array) array.each_with_index.collect do |element, index| if index == 1 then element else element[element.length] = "s"; element end end end
```

However, I am not entirely sure why you want that code on one line, because your original version is much more readable.

Answer (score -2):

It's easy to achieve this using 'active_support'

```
arr = ["hand", "feet", "knee", "table"]

2.0.0-p648 :023 > require 'active_support/inflector'
 => true

arr.map { |a| arr.index(a) == 1 ? a : a.pluralize }
 => ["hands", "feet", "knees", "tables"]
```

Comment: There is no `active_support` in Ruby core.

Comment: ActiveSupport's [pluralize
method](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/String:pluralize) does not simply add a `"s"` to the end of a string.